# Is there a better way to send the form data?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I tried sending my form data through `axios` using the following method. But I want to know if there is a better way to send the form data, so that my code looks standard with a fewer lines of code.

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" class="forms__first" placeholder="First Name*" v-model="firstName">
        <input type="text" class="forms__last" placeholder="Last Name*" v-model="lastName">
        <input type="email" class="forms__email" placeholder="Email*" v-model="email">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="forms__number"
          placeholder="Phone Number (Optional)"
          v-model="number"
        >
        <input
          type="text"
          class="forms__add"
          placeholder="Address (e.g: Shankhamul, Kathmandu)"
          v-model="address"
        >
```

Script Code

```
sendUserInfo () {
    axios
      .post('/formdata/store', {
        first_name: this.firstName,
        last_name: this.lastName,
        email: this.email,
        phone_no: this.number,
        address: this.address
      })
      .then(res => {
        alert('successfully posted')
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

Comment: Can you please share more details where `this` comes from? What your form looks like? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Having such an example - we can help you in a better way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oh! I was unaware of that community. Thanks for sharing. @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would recommend to nest all those individual data-models under one data-model as so:

```js
data() {
    return {
        user: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: ''
       }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to refer to those in your html as

```html
<input type="text" class="forms__first" placeholder="First Name*" v-model="user.firstName">
```

But the benefit is in your `sendUserInfo` function where you will achieve your objective of "my code looks standard with a fewer lines of code":

```js
sendUserInfo () {
    axios
      .post('/formdata/store', this.user)
```

Second, if your code is working then there is no real problem to solve through this question. I would then suggest you look more thoroughly to the VueJS officiel guides especially the Cookbook to see how common coding challenges should be tackled. Here is the [Axios recipe](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html).

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

you can use **.serializeArray()** for serializing your form data for POST

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

```
var data = $({YOUR_FORM_SELECTOR}).serializeArray();
axios.post('/formdata/store', data)
      .then(res => {
        alert('successfully posted')
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

If you don't need jQuery, use **FormData** class of javascript

```
var form = document.querySelector({YOUR_FORM_SELECTOR});
var data = new FormData(form);
axios.post('/formdata/store', data)
          .then(res => {
            alert('successfully posted')
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the form into a `form` object, which you can declare in the `data` section as an empty JS object. Then you just bind the attributes to that object in the template using `v-model="form.firstName"` etc. Finally, you can just submit the `form` object with axios using `this.form`.